# Compare .innerHTML with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a play/pause button and I want to check whether its text is "Play" or "Pause" when the user clicks on it.

```
window.PlayPauseButton = document.getElementById("PlayPauseButton");

PlayPauseButton.onclick = function()  //when you click the play or pause button
{
    if( window.PlayPauseButton.innerHTML == "Pause" )
    {
        window.PlayPauseButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        clearInterval( window.TheTimer );
    }
    else
    {
        window.PlayPauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    }
};
```

But it doesn't work! I can't compare innerHTML with a string.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a string value and compares to strings quite nicely.  However, you have not included the HTML nor the error message, so all someone can do is guess.  "It doesn't work" is the worst description of a bug -- you should always say exactly WHAT isn't happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check with innerText, not innerHTML

```
PlayPauseButton.onclick = function()  //when you click the play or pause button
{
    if( window.PlayPauseButton.innerText== "Pause" )
    {
        window.PlayPauseButton.innerText= "Play";
        clearInterval( window.TheTimer );
    }
    else
    {
        window.PlayPauseButton.innerText= "Pause";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a button tag, try using `innerText` instead:

```
if (window.PlayPauseButton.innerText == "Pause" ){
    window.PlayPauseButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    clearInterval( window.TheTimer );
}
else  {
    window.PlayPauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
}
```

This will only work if you're using `<button>Play</button>`.

If you're using an `<input type="button">` you're going to need to compare the value instead of `innerText`.